# selector does not working when it is set to focus

Tags: css, css-selectors, focus, selector

I am trying to create a menu button, to show-hide the menu on mobile devices.

If I set the selector to :hover, or :active, it is ok, but when I set the selector to :focus, nothing happens.

```
<div class = "menu-show-hide"></div>

<div class = "header-menu">
    <div class="menu-header-left-container">
        <ul>
            <li>...</li>
            <li>...</li>

        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-header-right-container">
        <ul>
            <li>...</li>
            <li>...</li>

        </ul>
    </div>
</div><!-- .header-menu   -->
```

css:

```
.menu-show-hide {
    position: relative;
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    background: url(menu-button.png) center no-repeat;
    z-index: 9999;
}
.header-menu {
    position: relative;
    display: none;
}
/* working */
.menu-show-hide:active ~ .header-menu {
    display: block;
}
/* not working */
.menu-show-hide:focus ~ .header-menu {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: if you want focus a div-element, you have to add a tabindex attribute to this div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the tabindex attribute on the div to get the focus working.

https://snook.ca/archives/accessibility_and_usability/elements_focusable_with_tabindex

```css
div {
  margin: 10px;
}

div:focus {
  border: 2px solid red;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div>click here - div without tabindex</div>

<div tabindex="1">click here - div with tabindex</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the tabindex is a great way to achieve what you're tyring to do. However, there are some things you might want to explore. The tabindex attribute is mostly used for keyboard access, though you might use it with the css "focus" as well.

Please check the values you should use to the index at this page: https://web.dev/control-focus-with-tabindex

Kind regards,